# Java - String and array references

Tags: java, arrays, string

Just started to learn Java, and saw that both string and array are reference types.
I don't understand the following issue:

```
    String a = "a1";
    String b = "a2";
    a=b;
    a = "rrr";

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);

    int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
    int[] arr2 = arr1;
    arr2[0]= 19;
    System.out.println(arr1[0]);
```

When I print it, I get : `"rrr" "a2" 10`

when using arrays - I understand that they are both pointing on the same object, so if I change the cell - I see the difference both at arr1 and arr2.

regarding "string" - from my understanding when I do : a=b it shouldn't be : "let `a` point on the same object as `b` is pointing" - meaning if I change a that they both need also to be changed?

Thanks!!

Comment: This isn't the most useful thing, but I think you would appreciate knowing that you can print an array with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));`.

Comment: Start making distinctions between _variables_, _reference values_, and _instances_ (objects).

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the array case, you're actually modifying the array, and thus if one reference is changed, so is the other.

In the string case, you are **not** modifying the object, you are simply assigning a **different** object to that reference.
As you noted: `a=b` means "let a point to the same object as b is pointing". Following the same line of thought, `a="rrr"` means "let a point to the literal "rrr"", which has nothing to do with with b.

Answer (score 1):

So, *reassignment* is a different thing from *modification*.

If you have

```
String a = "foo";
String b = a;
```

then you have *assigned* `b` to refer to the same object as `a`.
If you then do

```
b = "bananas";
```

then you haven't modified the string, you have *reassigned* b so it is no longer referring to the same object as `a`.

On the other hand

```
int[] c = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] d = c;
```

Here again we have `d` assigned to refer to the same object (an array) as `c`. If you then do something like this:

```
d[0] = 10;
```

then you are *modifying* the contents of the array that both `c` and `d` refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 string objects and 1 array object.

"a1", "a2", "rrr"

{1,2,3}

```
String a = "a1"; // a points to a new object "a1"
String b = "a2"; // b points to a new object "a2"
a=b; // a points to b's object "a2"
a = "rrr"; // a points to new object "rrr"

System.out.println(a); // prints "rrr" to console
System.out.println(b); // Prints "a2" to console

int[] arr1 = {1,2,3}; // arr1 points to new array {1,2,3}
int[] arr2 = arr1; // arr2 points to array in arr1 {1,2,3}
arr2[0]= 19; // modifies the array arr2 points to {19, 2, 3}
System.out.println(arr1[0]); // Prints "19" to console
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all String is a immutable. Immutalbe means that you cannot change the object itself, but you can change the reference.
Like in your case -

```
    String a = "a1"; // a is a reference variable and point to new object with value "a1"

    String b = "a2"; // b is a reference and point to new object with value "a2"

    a=b; // now a is referencing same object as b is referencing, a and b value is "a2"

    a = "rrr"; // at this time "rrr" is creating a new String object with value "rrr" and now a is pointing to this object.
```

So b is still point to "a2" and now a is pointing to new object "rrr". That's why both print different value.

```
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
```